# How to make chrome access local files...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have json files that I need to use in my script. I am using $.getJSON method to access these files. All is working fine in firefox, but due to same origin policy in chrome, its not able to access the files.

Using this "chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files", makes it access them, but is there any other way to make it access them.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanx

Comment: if a browser could access files on your local system without your permission, don't you think that this would be a serious security flaw? Go to this website so that I can upload your hard drive to my server, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use `JSONP` instead of `JSON` so you're not restricted by the Same Origin Policy, which affects FireFox as well as IE and Chrome.